# Calculate a subquery several times in WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

In SQL, I want to check whether the result of a subquery ((SELECT ...)) is either X or Y but not Z. Is there anyway not calculate the subquery 3 times?

```
 SELECT *
 FROM   User
 WHERE  (X IN (SELECT ...) OR Y IN (SELECT ...) )
 AND 'Z' NOT IN (SELECT ...);
```

Comment: Yes, should be possible. Add some sample table data and the expected result as well. (Formatted text please.)

Comment: Is your lookup query the same for X, Y and Z?

Comment: @vitalygolub Yes, all subqueries are the same.